# Как правильно добавить groupBy?

Tags: laravel

на сайте есть категории, а у категорий есть характеристики, у некоторых категорий бывает что какая то часть характеристик схожа, и мне нужно убрать эти дубликаты, то есть оставить у категорий только уникальные характеристики, и хотелось бы это сделать запросом к БД а не в контроллере с помощью php.
В итоге я делаю такой вот запрос к БД:

```
$categories = Category::whereIn('id',$request->input('categories'))->with(['characteristics' => function($query) {
        $query->groupBy('id');
    }])->get();
```

laravel генерирует такой вот запрос:

```
select `characteristics`.*, `category_characteristic`.`category_id` as `pivot_category_id`, `category_characteristic`.`characteristic_id` as `pivot_characteristic_id` from `characteristics` inner join `category_characteristic` on `characteristics`.`id` = `category_characteristic`.`characteristic_id` where `category_characteristic`.`category_id` in (51, 52) group by `id`
```

При таком запросе получаю ошибку:

```
Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'rqt1mvsaw_js3ht.category_characteristic.category_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Если же убрать из select всё и оставить только: `characteristics`.*
получается такой запрос:

```
select `characteristics`.* from `characteristics` inner join `category_characteristic` on `characteristics`.`id` = `category_characteristic`.`characteristic_id` where `category_characteristic`.`category_id` in (51, 52) group by `id`
```

И он срабатывает, но мне всё таки нужны поля из связующей таблицы category_characteristic. Связь у меня многое-ко-многим между характеристиками и категориями. Подскажите пожалуйста что тут можно сделать, заранее благодарю за ответ.

Comment: Ну, вариант не один.. Можно либо сменить `sql_mode`, либо в group by добавить параметры (можно массивом в саму ф-цию).

Comment: @InDevX спасибо за комментарий, а подскажите какие параметры ? Все поля которые перечисляются в select ?

Comment: Да, можете добавить все, перечисляемые в select